# Is every logical theory embeddable in a dependently typed extensional type theory?

Tags: type-theory, category-theory

In category theory by the Yoneda embedding every category $\mathcal{C}$ is a subcategory of a category of presheafs $[\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}, \text{Set}]$. Every category of presheafs is a topos and has an associated extensional dependent type theory. Is it the case that you can do the same thing with logical theories and every logical theory has an associated "dependent type theory of presheafs" which it embeds nicely in?

I suppose the details depend upon how you quite define a logical theory. At a highest level I think you want some (n+1)-category $\text{Th}$ of n-theories. I think without assuming some sort of strong object classifier like $\text{Set}$ I think you would want some sort of theory of discrete fibrations of theories $\text{ThDis}(\mathcal{T})$.

I'd assume if you have a syntax semantics equivalence given by functors $\text{Syn}$ and $\text{Lang}$ then $\text{Lang}(\text{Set})$ probably ought to work as some kind of object classifier. Or something like $\text{Lang}([\text{Syn}(\mathcal{T})^{\text{op}}, \text{Set}])$ probably ought to work well enough. But I'm not at all sure here of the details here.

I think computation ought to be a mild wrinkle in things. I have a feeling you can maybe handle computation using a sort of "double theory" equivalent to double categories? But this is a hunch.

It's also not really clear to me that a "Yoneda embedding of theories" ought to be very nice to work with. You would probably like an embedding which in some way is lax monoidal and oplaxed closed so there are maps $\text{Yo}(A) \otimes \text{Yo}(B) \rightarrow \text{Yo}(A \otimes B)$ and $\text{Yo}([A, B]) \rightarrow [\text{Yo}(A), \text{Yo}(B)]$ and so you can treat the embedded language as a sort of applicative functor like DSL. I'm not very good at topos theory but this sort of condition feels familiar to me. But it feels like variable binders ought to be a headache. I think the most naive view of variable binders ought to be a map $[\text{Yo}(A), \text{Yo}(B)]\rightarrow \text{Yo}([A,B])$ which seems very dubious to me. So I doubt some form of higher order abstract syntax would be very easy.

Comment: Isn't this question better suited for MathOverflow?

Comment: I agree --- it's a good question, but its answer involves things like "grothendieck topologies", which makes me think it belongs on MO.

Comment: @AndrejBauer TBH I'm kind of shy of posting on MO because I'm hypersensitive to rejection and the people there are kind of snippy. If you think this is a good question for MO IDK how someone with perms would move the question but I wouldn't be against exactly.

Comment: There are probably more people who can answer this sort of question on MO than here, that was my main point. It's true that MO is a not for the faint-hearted, that's true unfortunately.